# TDS SFX missing from all scenes and encounters after recent patches

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Anyone else noticed after recent patches, that the rebel encounters, the scenes in the album and maybe some other stuff too have lost their sound effects ?
I mean there's no sfx anymore, and if the music is playing when you start a scene, the music doesn't cut off like it should.

iPhone5 IOS 7.04
Game 1.3.2700, Data 1.4.0.0

Have rebooted the phone, tried closing the game aswell but nothing helps.

Suggesting this must be a bug with some recent patching ?

Comment: What platform?  You may need to reinstall the game.

Comment: Just reinstalled the game but seems i've lost my Deathstar now. Now this sucks... I'm just so tired into this bullshit, going to uninstall for good now.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I keep the sound off so it doesn't bother me. For those who want to reload on iOS make sure your game is attached to Facebook or backed up, otherwise deleting and reloading the app will reset the game.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star):

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

If you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming**.

As you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Comment: Note: this answer is a [community-proposed solution](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13064/28182) for unresolved Tiny Death Star bug questions.